# Skype 2.0.72 - download for Fedora Centos

Tags: fedora, skype, centos

Still today we dont have the SkypeKIT in Hand. I need a way to implement the project, where the project deadline is end of this Aug, 2010. I figure out that i can do it using ALSA sound driver.

I need to download Skype 2.0.72 (fedora/centos version). Almost searched whole google, there is not a single download link available for that release.

Can anyone please kindly give atleast a Skype 2.0.72 old version download link for getting it installed in Fedora 12/CentOS 5.4 ??

This is with new version of Skype 2.1.x

```
[root@example configs]# ls
client.c copy create multiple-instance-same-skype-username README.skypopen_auth skypopen_auth skypopen_auth.c skypopen.conf.xml startskype2.sh startskype.bat startskype.sh wait.bat windows-service
[root@example configs]# vi startskype2.sh
[root@example configs]# sh ./startskype2.sh
ERROR: Module snd_hda_intel is in use
ERROR: Module snd_dummy is in use

Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 101
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X101-lock
and start again.

[root@example configs]# freeswitch

2010-08-22 16:32:56.810361 [ERR] skypopen_protocol.c:233 rev [(nil)|37 ][ERRORA 233 ][interface1][-1, 0, 0] Skype got ERROR: |||ERROR 589 ALTER CALL: unable to alter input/output|||
2010-08-22 16:32:56.810361 [ERR] skypopen_protocol.c:235 rev [(nil)|37 ][ERRORA 235 ][interface1][-1, 0,16] skype_call now is DOWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab Skype 2.0.72 from [RPMFind](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/6009449/dir/pld/com/skype-2.0.0.27-1.i586.rpm.html).